# Sum of Doubles that where parsed from a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, double, number-formatting

How to get the sum of `Doubles` that where parsed from a `JTable`?

I'm Building a Client/Server Application, and I'm Stuck on a Little issue.

I want get the sum of values of a column in a `JTable`, this column contains `String` objects with `#,##` format, so when I try to parse them into doubles with a loop I get this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,55"
```

Here is the `JTable` image:

[image]

And here is the code that I tried so far:

```
    private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    {                                          

    Double summl = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++){
        summl=summl+Double.parseDouble(jTable1.getValueAt(i,5).toString());
    }
     System.out.println("summl = "+summl);
   }
```

Comment: the model column should contain Double instead of String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with the comma in the number. You should try to parse the numbers using [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class.

E.G.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH); //Set the proper locale here

        try {
            Double myDouble = (Double)nf.parse("0,55");
            System.out.println(myDouble);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanx, that's Exactly what I've been Missing.