# How to Divise the doubles into separated collected Values

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, double

I'm building a client/server application, and I need your help on the following problem.

I have a `JTable` as u see in the image below:

[image]

and I want to get a bottle for every client, a `bottle=("Flacon")` should have:

- Maximum 9,9 ml in each bottle.
- Maximum 5 Doses in each bottle.

Here is the code I tried:

```
private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)         {                                          

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
    int dose=0;
    Double summl =0.0;
    String Name="";
    Vector  vf = null;
    Vector<Vector> data = new Vector<Vector>();

    for(int i=0; i <jTable1.getRowCount(); i++)
    {

        try {
                if(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1).toString().equals(jTable1.getValueAt(i+1, 1).toString()))
                {

                    dose++;
                    summl=summl+(Double)nf.parse(jTable1.getValueAt(i,5).toString());
                    Name=jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();

                }else
                {
                    vf=new Vector();   
                    vf.add(countflac);
                    vf.add(Name);
                    vf.add(summl);
                    data.add(vf);
                    countflac++;
                }

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    jTable3.setModel(new DefaultTableModel( data,vflac));
    System.out.println("Sum of ml's ="+summl);
    System.out.println("dose ="+dose);

}
```

and it gives the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:  Invalid index

Comment: repeating myself (from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342069/sum-of-doubles-that-where-parsed-from-a-jtable): the model column should contain Double instead of String - if you dont change that quickly, you'll run into endless maintenance problems. The model is meant to contain the _data_, not the representation of the data. The latter is the responsibility of the view, which in case of JTable is delegating to its renderers - that's where you configure the visuals, f.i. by supplying the default number renderer with a NumberFormat as appropriate

Comment: i can't becuz my whole application is based on the DefaultTableModel.

Comment: plus: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: sure you can, the default model is _designed_ to take whatever objects you throw into it

Comment: i know, it's just that i'm in a bit of rush :(

Comment: hacking around all the problems that will arise by your extremely suboptimal setup (you are fighting the framework instead of using it as designed) will cost you waaaayyyy more time than simply doing it right near the start. Your decision, of course - but take into account that I'll most likely pin-point that wound again, next time you'll run into trouble, there is only a near-zero probability that I'll let stand bad examples uncommented ;-)

Comment: Thank you Very much, i like your attitude.

Answer (score 1):

```
getValueAt(i+1, 1)
```

Goes wrong for the last row as i+1 must be less than getRowCount().